# How to center vertically content in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want center vertically content in bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 align-middle">
                        <h1 class="about-title">Wil je in contact komen met betrouwbare verhuisbedrijven?</h1>
                        <p class="about-para">Ontdek binnen een paar minuten welke verhuisbedrijven passen bij jouw
                            verhuizing.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5 align-middle">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="form-outline">
                                <input id="search-focus" placeholder="Je postcode" type="search" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Ontvang offertes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i want to center vertically this content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with `.align-items-center`.

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h1 class="about-title">Wil je in contact komen met betrouwbare verhuisbedrijven?</h1>
                <p class="about-para">Ontdek binnen een paar minuten welke verhuisbedrijven passen bij jouw verhuizing.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 align-middle">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="form-outline">
                        <input id="search-focus" placeholder="Je postcode" type="search" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Ontvang offertes
                            </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex class to make align-center like *d-flex align-items-center* or you can check full documentation on the official bootstrap website:- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score -1):

- I am not too sure about alone with Bootstrap, because it depends upon your container height. In you case, it would be equal to your content.
- So, For Aligning it's content vertically, you need to set it's container height to 100% to its view. for ex, height:100vh.
- Then, after you could use flexbox classes provided by bootstrap on that container
- 1. d-flex -> to set display flex.
- 2. align-items-center -> to set align center vertically.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" style="height:100vh;">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 align-middle">
        <h1 class="about-title">Wil je in contact komen met betrouwbare verhuisbedrijven?</h1>
        <p class="about-para">Ontdek binnen een paar minuten welke verhuisbedrijven passen bij jouw verhuizing.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5 align-middle">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="form-outline">
            <input id="search-focus" placeholder="Je postcode" type="search" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Ontvang offertes
                            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```